# Adjusting dataset/model from example to predict value four timesteps ahead

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm just beginning to start with machine learning and want to predict values/sales in a timeseries. I found this two blog posts, which basically match what I'm looking for.

1. [Basics of Time Series Prediction](https://iq.opengenus.org/time-series-prediction/) - Setup of the Timeseries and Datasets found in here
2. [Techniques for Time Series Prediction](https://iq.opengenus.org/time-series-prediction-techniques/) - NN Setup in here

Instead of predicting the value for the next timestep I would like to predict the value 4 timesteps ahead. Originally I have weekly data, so I want to predict the value 4 weeks / 1 month ahead.

As I understand this, I therefor need to change the "label" the model is trained with, which will be done within the function `windowed_dataset()` (Source 2).

```
def windowed_dataset(series, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
  dataset = dataset.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
  dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size + 1))
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer).map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1])) # <-- change will be in here
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
  return dataset
```

If I change `dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer).map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1]))` to `dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer).map(lambda window: (window[:-4], window[-1]))` the labels in my opinion are correctly adjusted to my goal.

But running the next step

```
dataset = windowed_dataset(x_train, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer_size)
print(dataset)
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[window_size])
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([l0])


model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-6, momentum=0.9))
model.fit(dataset,epochs=100,verbose=0)
```

throws an error:

```
runcell('Build model', 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Local/Prediction/untitled0.py')
<PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Local\Prediction\untitled0.py", line 102, in <module>
    model.fit(dataset,epochs=100,verbose=0)

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential_9/dense_10/BiasAdd' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
      start.main()
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 328, in main
      kernel.start()
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1890, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 457, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 446, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 353, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 648, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 353, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2901, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2947, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3172, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3364, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15784/4252985979.py", line 1, in <module>
      runcell('Build model', 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Local/Prediction/untitled0.py')
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 673, in runcell
      exec_code(cell_code, filename, ns_globals, ns_locals,
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 465, in exec_code
      exec(compiled, ns_globals, ns_locals)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Local\Prediction\untitled0.py", line 102, in <module>
      model.fit(dataset,epochs=100,verbose=0)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 889, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 458, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 596, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dense.py", line 232, in call
      outputs = tf.nn.bias_add(outputs, self.bias)
Node: 'sequential_9/dense_10/BiasAdd'
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [24,9], In[1]: [12,1]
     [[{{node sequential_9/dense_10/BiasAdd}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_231055]
```

What am I missing here? Is there another, better approach to model the timeseries?

*Note: Somewhere in the future I also would like to add more parameters/indicators to the model to test if this increases the accuracy.*

**Edit:**
Creation of Data and Series:

```
#%% Setup 

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras

#%% Creating Timeseries

def plot_series(time, series, format="-", start=0, end=None):
    plt.plot(time[start:end], series[start:end], format)
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Value")
    plt.grid(True)

def trend(time, slope=0):
    return slope * time

def seasonal_pattern(season_time):
    """Just an arbitrary pattern, you can change it if you wish"""
    return np.where(season_time < 0.4,
                    np.cos(season_time * 2 * np.pi),
                    1 / np.exp(3 * season_time))

def seasonality(time, period, amplitude=1, phase=0):
    """Repeats the same pattern at each period"""
    season_time = ((time + phase) % period) / period
    return amplitude * seasonal_pattern(season_time)

def noise(time, noise_level=1, seed=None):
    rnd = np.random.RandomState(seed)
    return rnd.randn(len(time)) * noise_level

time = np.arange(4 * 365 + 1, dtype="float32")
baseline = 10
series = trend(time, 0.1)  
baseline = 10
amplitude = 40
slope = 0.05
noise_level = 5

# Create the series
series = baseline + trend(time, slope) + seasonality(time, period=365, amplitude=amplitude)
# Update with noise
series += noise(time, noise_level, seed=42)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plot_series(time, series)
plt.show()

#%% Create Data Sets
split_time = 1000
time_train = time[:split_time]
x_train = series[:split_time]
time_valid = time[split_time:]
x_valid = series[split_time:]
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plot_series(time_train, x_train)
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plot_series(time_valid, x_valid)
plt.show()
```

Parameters:

```
#%% Set Parameters
window_size = 4
batch_size = 4
shuffle_buffer_size = 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer).map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1]))` to `dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer).map(lambda window: (window[:-4], window[-1]))` will actually influence the window, as one can find out looking at the outputs of these following steps:

```
# Previous steps within function
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
dataset = dataset.window(12 + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(12 + 1))
```

```
# Regular approach predicting the next value
dataset_1 = dataset.shuffle(3).map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1]))

counter = 0
for n in dataset_1:
    counter +=1
    if counter == 1:
        print(n)

Output: 
> (<tf.Tensor: shape=(12,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([52.48357 , 49.35275 , 53.314735, 57.711823, 48.934444, 48.931244,
       57.982895, 53.897125, 47.67393 , 52.68371 , 47.591717, 47.506374],
      dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=50.959415>)
```

```
# Approach predicting a value 4 timesteps ahead
dataset_4 = dataset.shuffle(3).map(lambda window: (window[:-4], window[-1]))

counter = 0
for n in dataset_4:
    counter +=1
    if counter == 1:
        print(n)

Output:
> (<tf.Tensor: shape=(9,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([52.48357 , 49.35275 , 53.314735, 57.711823, 48.934444, 48.931244,
       57.982895, 53.897125, 47.67393 ], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=50.959415>)
```

In the first (regular) case the tensor has `shape (12,)` while in the second case the tensor has `shape (9,)`.

It is therefor necessary to adjust the `window_size` in the following steps to reflect the actual shape and its influences e.g. on the length of the result array.

```
window_size_adjusted = window_size - 3

dataset = windowed_dataset(x_train, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer_size)


#%% Build model
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[window_size_adjusted])
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([l0])


model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-6, momentum=0.9))
model.fit(dataset,epochs=100,verbose=0)

#%% Forecast
forecast = []

for time in range(len(series) - window_size_adjusted):
  forecast.append(model.predict(series[time:time + window_size_adjusted][np.newaxis]))

forecast = forecast[split_time-window_size_adjusted:]
results = np.array(forecast)[:, 0, 0]
```